# Duration calculation and control in ROS - furthermore why does this script keep running even after pressing Ctrl-C?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ros

I have written some code to make the turtlebot turn around. The code is working. What I want to know is how fast the turtlebot is running  and how I can control it. Forexample, how can I ensure that the turtlebot turns 5 degrees in one minute?
Last part of the question. After pressing Ctrl-C, the turtlebot stops but the script keeps running. Why? and how can I stop that?

[this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/294440/ros-python-script-is-not-exiting-after-ctrl-c/)  does not really help.

went through  [this post](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Time_and_Duration) .Does that mean that the ***while*** loop below runs 5 times a second regardless of the values I put in the ***for*** loops? Or does it mean ROS tries its best to make sure that the loop runs 5 times a second to the best of  my machine's ability?
Thank you very much.

```
# 5 HZ
angle = 5
r = rospy.Rate(5);
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    # code to turn
    for x in range(0,100):
        rospy.loginfo("turn")
        turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(angle) 
        new_angle = (angle + new_angle) % 360
        self.cmd_vel.publish(turn_cmd)
        r.sleep()
     # code to pause  
    for x in range(0,100):
        rospy.loginfo("stop")
        turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(0)
        self.cmd_vel.publish(turn_cmd)

        r.sleep()

def shutdown(self):
    # stop turtlebot
    rospy.loginfo("Stop turning")
    self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
    rospy.sleep(1)
```

Comment: "rospy provides a rospy.Rate convenience class which makes a best effort at maintaining a particular rate for a loop. "  [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates)    I am not sure though what happens if you call `r.sleep()` multiple times in the while loop.

Comment: alright, assuming that i do not call `r.sleep()` at all in the while loop, then what would be the estimated rate?

Comment: Then it would be just a normal python while loop without ROS interference. So The frequency depends on the code execution time within the while loop. Normally you would just call `r.sleep()` once at the end of the while loop to ensure the frequency.

Comment: [Here is a further explanation of rospy.Rate](https://answers.ros.org/question/264812/explanation-of-rospyrate/)

Comment: so that means it would running at 5Hz, right? So does that have anything to do with the script not stopping to run even after pressing the `Ctrl + C` command. ROS stops but the loops keep on running for a while till all iterations are done. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Yes, rospy.Rate() does its best to ensure the loop running in 5Hz - as long as you code execution within a loop does not exceed 1/5 seconds. I am not sure about the script not stopping, but my theory is that rospy catches the KeyboardInterrupt signal (and basically overrides it such that KeyboardInterrupt with ctrl-c does not behave like a normal python script). Rospy then uses the keyboardInterrupt signal to set the rospy.is_shutdown() flag to true, which is only checked at the end of the while loop, thus only terminating after the for loops.

Comment: Apparently you can manually initiate a shutdown by using `rospy.signal_shutdown()` , but you have to set the flag `disable_signals` to true when initializing the ROS node. See section 2.3 of this [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown)

Comment: @rfn123 thanks. I believe your theory is true. Indeed using the `signal_shutdown()` solved the issue. Convert your second last comment to an answer. It's that information that led to a solution I desire anyway. so I guess that pretty much answers my question. Thank you. Oh the last part is also important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates), the `rospy.Rate` convenience class makes a best effort to maintain the loop running at the specified frequency by considering the execution time of the loop since the last successful `r.sleep()`. This means in your case: as long as the code execution time within the loop does not exceed 1/5 seconds, `rospy.Rate` will make sure the loop runs at 5Hz.

Regarding the script not stopping when pressing Ctrl-C:
`KeyboardInterrupt` will be handled differently than in normal Python scripts when using `rospy`.
`rospy` catches the `KeyboardInterrupt` signal to set the `rospy.is_shutdown()` flag to true. This flag is only checked at the end of each loop, therefore if pressing Ctrl-C during the for-loop executions, the script cannot be stopped because the flag is not checked immediately.

A manual way to signal a shutdown of the node is to use `rospy.signal_shutdown()`. For this, the `disable_signals` option needs to be set to true when initializing the ROS node (see Section 2.3 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown)). Note that you will additionally have to manually invoke the correct shutdown routines to ensure a proper cleanup.